# I want to sort integers by the number of 1 bits

Tags: java, stream, bit-manipulation

```
class Solution {
    public int[] sortByBits(int[] arr) {
        return Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().sorted((a, b) -> Integer.bitCount(a) == Integer.bitCount(b) ? a - b : Integer.bitCount(a) - Integer.bitCount(b)).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
    }
}
```

I just started experimenting with java streams, and I found this solution for sorting integers by the number of 1 bits when given an array. I like the solution, but I don't understand whats going on after the stream is boxed. I'd really appreciate it if someone can break down each step starting with '.sorted(...'

Maybe if someone can provide a better easier to understand solution for what .sort is doing, I would very much appreciate it.

Last thing I'm a bit unclear about this solution is what the '.mapToInt(Integer::intValue)' is doing at the end of the statement. Specifically what is the purpose of 'intValue'.

Sorry if my questions seem a bit primitive, I just discovered streams and I see a lot of potential for it. I want to make sure I really understand everything going on.

Comment: It's slightly more complicated than just sorting by the number of 1 bits. If two values have the *same* number of 1 bits then those values are ordered smallest to largest as ints. I think `mapToInt(Integer::intValue)` is unboxing the stream.

Comment: `mapToInt(Integer::intValue)` just converts a `Stream<Integer>` to an `IntStream`.  That's it.  (Personally, I'd write `mapToInt(x -> x)`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of IDE "un-lambdaing" later ;-)

```java
class Solution {
  public int[] sortByBits(int[] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)
        .boxed()    // boxing for sorting with Comparator
        .sorted(new Comparator<Integer>() {
          @Override
          public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
            if(Integer.bitCount(a) == Integer.bitCount(b)) { 
              // if both have the same number of bits
              return a - b;    // smaller int value first
            }
            // otherwise least number of bits first
            return Integer.bitCount(a) - Integer.bitCount(b); 
          }
        })
        .mapToInt(new ToIntFunction<Integer>() { // unboxing
          @Override
          public int applyAsInt(Integer integer) {
            return integer.intValue();
          }
        }).toArray();  // array from stream
  }
}
```